# Is it possible to force Business Objects 6.5 to create proper ANSI joins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, business-objects

The SQL that Business Objects generates seems to be stuck in a bygone era for SQL joins -- it insists on using the old Sybase outer-join syntax (*=, etc.), which is illegal in SQL Server 2005 when running at level 90. Is there an option somewhere to make it use modern join syntax (i.e., joining using the JOIN keyword rather than using commas in the FROM statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, there's a universe parameter called ANSI92 that does exactly what you want.